# What am I doing wrong with npm susy and grunt?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, susy-compass, susy, susy-sass

I am trying to compile my scss files using susy, node-sass, grunt-sass
I added all these dependencies using npm install.
I am adding the setup for grunt like

```
sass: {
      options: {
        implementation: sass,
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          require: 'susy'
        },
        files: {
          'app/crossbrand_us/styleguide/css/shared.css': 'app/sass/xb/widgets/advertised-offers/wdgt-advertised-offers-vehicle.scss'
        }
      }
    },
```

```
@import "wdgt-advertised-offers-shared";
@import "node_modules/susy/sass/susy";
$wdgt-advertised-offers-vehicle-selector: ".wdgt-advertised-offers-vehicle";

#{$wdgt-advertised-offers-vehicle-selector} {
    @include pad(1%);
 }
```

but this throws an error

```
Fatal error: no mixin named pad
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest versions](https://oddbird.net/2017/06/28/susy3/) of Susy (3.x) do not include any mixins. In order to use the old mixins, you will have to downgrade to a 2.x version of Susy (2.2.14 is the latest). Or check out [the docs](https://oddbird.net/susy/docs/) to get started with Susy 3.

I'm not sure if there are any other issues in the setup as well…

Comment: Yup, that was the case. I was trying to change a old project with nodejs, I down graded to 2.2.12 as gem install susy does. And it started to roll. :)

Comment: glad to hear it!